# CSS3 transform rotate vs using images

Tags: css, rotation, css-transforms

I'm working on a site that uses images diagonally aligned.  The images are fairly simple and have some text inside so I can achieve the effect using either images or the CSS3 `transform: rotate` and `border-radius` properties, granted, with all the proprietary extensions.

However I'm wondering if there are significant advantages for using one over the other.  I'm thinking maybe the CSS-only alternative would load faster, but a downside would be the use of more code for each image.  Although using images I'd still have to do a lot of positioning for each element.  Also, the CSS in the first case would not validate using browser-specific extensions, how important is this if I still make sure the site is correctly displayed in most browsers?

Is there a general approach for using either one of these options? What would you recommend?

Comment: Thank you for your answers.  I'm choosing David's because that the option I'm going for with the design, but your comments will help me prevent some other issues as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of CSS3, versus images, is best answered by your need to support Internet Explorer (or *other* older, or CSS3-unaware, browsers): if a large portion of your user-base browses with IE then you should use images.

If you're only interested in the later, more standards-compliant, browsers (possibly including IE9, but I've no experience with it as yet) then CSS 3 is likely the better option, since it might involve a larger CSS file, but it does allow you to switch your layout more easily in future, without having to create/recreate a new set of images for the new design.

You could, of course, combine both approaches: use CSS 3 for the compliant browsers, but include an IE-specific stylesheet, with [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html), to supply the images as, perhaps, background-images to build up the design. This is, of course, likely to be a lot of work, though.

Comment: You're right David.  I was considering a IE-specific CSS and the use of -ms-filter to compensate, but perhaps the images would be easier just for this browser.  I'd like to try out some other possibilities of CSS3 so I might go with that :)

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly recommend an image for this. CSS3 is cool, but browsers that don't support it might break your layout. Also (possibly more importantly), text really needs proper anti-aliasing to be readable when rotated or scaled, and you can get finer control over that with an image.

Comment: Anti-aliasing is a good point, I hadn't considered it.  I could go with only images of the text over the ones generated with CSS, I guess.  I did some tests now and Opera and Chrome look fine but FF shows the text slightly uneven.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I think you should consider here:

1. Images are a killer for those on mobile devices.  So if you are targeting those with mobile or expect a large mobile audience, you may want to reconsider using a lot of images (and having your users pay a ton in bandwidth).
2. The text in your images (if you use images) will not be searchable by search engines and will not be accessible for those with accessibility issues, unless you are good at filling in your `alt` tags. ;-)

Comment: Thank you Jason. I'm targeting mobile devices as well so another reason to reconsider images; and I'm pretty strict when it comes to filling in alt tags so no problem there :)